# Android: different ways of storing and reading variable values?

Tags: java, android, storage

I have about 16 variables in which the values need to be saved for later recall / editing. I've tried SQLite Database, since I am a novice at Android, it is just too hard for me. I will have to come back to SQL later. Are there any other ways to store these values for later recall / editing? Thank you! Maybe link me to a tutorial if possible? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: But I thought SharedPreferences could only save things like settings?

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is another choice. Here is a very simple [example](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.jp/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)
how to use it.
Storing 16 variables using SharedPreferences will make your code looks long.
 I advise you to try harder with SQlite database.

Comment: Thanks Ninja. Do you know if I can use SharedPreferences across activities (of the same package)? If so, do I have to set the MODE to something other than MODE_PRIVATE?

Comment: You can share them through out your application without worrying. You will need to use other flags if you will be sharing your SharedPreferences with other applications, or if you will be using multiple processes. For pros / cons with sharedpreferences over a sqlite database, Like the name implies, sharedperferences are great - but have limitations. If you're storing user data (not settings), I would use a sqlite database as this provides much more felexibility. Don't forget, it's ok to use both! Both are good, and are used for two different things!

Comment: Yes you can use SharedPreferences across activities, thats one of the reasons it is very useful. Setting the mode to MODE_PRIVATE is to ensure that only your application can access it. All the activities in that application can access it.